# Read object from Json with Java (gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a problem reading the object in the Json file. I have tried treating it as an ArrayList, as an Object and I don't know what else to try because it gives me null. How can I get the items out of the object?

Imports

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.gson.*;
```

Json file

```
{
    "letters": 4,
    "numbers": 4,
    "positions": 4,
    "id":[[-1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1]],
    "wall":{
        "(0,0)":{"value":0,"walls": [false,true,true,false]},
        "(1,2)":{"value":0,"walls": [false,false,false,true]},
        "(5,7)":{"value":0,"walls": [false,true,false,false]},
        "(0,3)":{"value":0,"walls": [false,false,true,true]},
        "(2,8)":{"value":0,"walls": [true,false,true,false]}
    }
}
```

Java code

```
public static void readJson(String path) {
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String file_gson = "";
        
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))){
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                file_gson += line;  
            }
            Fich element = gson.fromJson(file_gson, Fich.class);
            System.out.println(element.letters);

        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("");
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

But in the object class (Walls) it doesn't read it to me. And it gives me an error if I put (walls) as string.

```
public class Fich{
    public int letters;
    public int numbers;
    public int positions;
    public ArrayList id;
    public Walls walls;
    
    
    public Fich(int letters, int numbers, Walls walls){
        this.letters = letters;
        this.letters = letters;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` field is an `JSON Array` which contains another `JSON Array`-s. You can map it to `List<List<Integer>>`. `wall` field is a `JSON Object` where keys are `String`-s and values are another `JSON Object`-s. You can map it to `Map<String, Wall>`.

See below example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path pathToJson = Paths.get("./resource/test.json");
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToJson)) {
            Fich fich = gson.fromJson(reader, Fich.class);
            System.out.println(fich);
        }
    }
}

class Fich {
    private int letters;
    private int numbers;
    private int positions;
    private List<List<Integer>> id;
    private Map<String, Wall> wall;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Wall {
    private int value;
    private List<Boolean> walls;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Fich[letters=4, numbers=4, positions=4, id=[[-1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1]], wall={(0,0)=Wall[value=0, walls=[false, true, true, false]], (1,2)=Wall[value=0, walls=[false, false, false, true]], (5,7)=Wall[value=0, walls=[false, true, false, false]], (0,3)=Wall[value=0, walls=[false, false, true, true]], (2,8)=Wall[value=0, walls=[true, false, true, false]]}]
```